# Multiple message in load mask in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I just want to show different messages.

```
 Ext.Viewport.setMasked({
   xtype: 'loadmask',
   message: 'Downloading data. Please wait...'
 });
```

When I download data from server I gave call to different functions.
Depending on function I want to change the message.

Please provide guide line or  working code.

I have used

```
Ext.Viewport.unmask();
```

in every function and reset the message in that function.. but showing same message.

Comment: can you please clarify by examples?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. Just get the Viewport loading mask, and update the message. Here is an example, once you set the loading mask and now want to change the text (or even other properties):

```
Ext.Viewport.getMasked().setMessage('This is a new message.');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var loadMask = Ext.getCmp('your view id which you want to use');
loadMask.setMessage(Get the message Dynamically or static);
```